# Python for reading and writing particular arp cache

Tags: python, arp

I'm trying to make a program that is able to, upon start, read the arp cache for the router (with its mac, ip etc) and then echo (or just write) it into a file. Then later when a particular event occurs, read the data and compare current cache with the previous. Anybody know the code to read the cache in python? (I'm working on a linux machine in case that matters)

Comment: @HarshWardhan code along the lins of `print (arp -a)` and then storing it as a variable from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install `python_arptable` :

```
pip install python_arptable
```

Then in your script :

```
 from python_arptable import get_arp_table

 print(get_arp_table())
```

It should return something like :

```
[{'Mask': '*', 'HW address': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx', 'IP address': 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx', 'HW type': '0x1', 'Flags': '0x2', 'Device': 'wlp2s0'}, {'Mask': '*', 'HW address': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx', 'IP address': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'HW type': '0x1', 'Flags': '0x2', 'Device': 'wlp2s0'}]
```

Comment: When I try to pip install the arp_table its throws me an error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement arp_table (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for arp_table"

Comment: yes, my bad. I edited my answer : `pip install python_arptable
`

Comment: Yes it worked @NabIlovich ! Now all i have is to do is copy certain parts of a certain ip. Appreciate the help